# Не берут Junior PHP программистом. Почему?

Tags: php, symfony

Всем добрый день. Прошу подсказать какие технологии надо подучить или что исправить в резюме, чтобы оно смотрелось более привлекательным для работодателя? Что нужно изменить на сайте?

"Добрый день. 
Самостоятельно изучаю PHP больше года. Из знаний могу выделить:

- знание PHP5, понимание и применение принципов ООП. Применение паттернов проектирования.
- знание Symfony2, TWIG
- знание Doctrine, MySQL
- опыт верстки сайтов на HTML/CSS/JavaScript/jQuery/Ajax/JSON
- знание Git-flow и Composer
- Знание английского язык на хорошем уровне.

Есть два тестовых сайта: 
 - dreamarts.by - сделан на чистом PHP
 - symfony.dreamarts.by - сделан на Symfony2

Из личных качеств: ответственность, терпение, усидчивость, стрессоустойчивость, умею доводить дело до конца. Быстро усваиваю новый материал. Математический склад ума. Умею расставлять приоритеты. Коммуникабельный, легко вливаюсь в новый коллектив. Умею слушать и слышать, умею задавать вопросы. Имею свою точку зрения и могу ее обосновать."

Comment: А где ссылка на портфолио? Вообще начитают приглашать если на stackoverflow рейтинг выше 10 000

Comment: Если вместо второго сайта видим "Server not found", то неудивительно, что не приглашают...

Comment: Что-то я поторопился, исправил ссылку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, что говорят: Ты программист? Покажи! (сразу при встрече выполнить задание какое-то - так проверяют сообразительность, скорость)
Можете врать, это приемлемо, но будьте готовы, что наниматель все проверит.
Пишите что вы умеете делать на PHP и на Symfony2 и т.д. Не надо писать, что вы знаете... Что знаете? Конкретно.
Возраст не имеет значения, напишите лучше что вы умеете концентрироваться.
Уберите "больше года" - этого недостаточно.
Шрифт с засечками замените. Разве его удобно читать?
"Из знаний могу выделить" здесь вы не уверены в себе.
Из личных качеств умею доводить дело до конца !!! очень важно !!!
Сделайте больше сайтов. Где верстка, только одна и все? Приложите код, он у вас читабелен или это машинный код одной строкой?

Cловам никто не верит, давайте результаты!

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Не очень понятно насчет "приложить код". Мне, как неопытному программисту, страшно выкладывать свой код, мало ли он еще больше отпугнет работодателя =). Вообще пытаюсь придерживаться стандарта PSR-2.

Comment: "Из знаний могу выделить" здесь вы не уверены в себе" Уверено в себе бывает только быдло. Как раз неуверенный человек - это элита, понимающая, что познание бесконечно, и ничто нельзя изучить до мелочей. Много кто без гугла ответит, что loop на masm с телом из большого количества invoke может работать неправильно из-за дальности перехода и подготовки вызовов функций?

Comment: @user196861 собственнику компании требуется быстрая программа, с корректно работающим функционалом, красивым дизайном и как можно быстрее чтобы генерировала прибыль. Поэтому, обычно, резюме проверяет HR или IT-директор. Первый смотрит психологический портрет, второй как раз таки код и работы. Говорите без лишних слов и самое главное доказывайте. Это без разницы, если вас пригласят по резюме, то вам придется проявить себя на собеседовании и тем более в работе. Как в боксе, чем больше поединков, тем опытнее боксер. Представьте если бы он боялся выйти на ринг потому что не уверен в своем ударе!

Answer (score 0):

Что я сделал бы по другому на главной странице первого сайта:

- Длинное объяснение что это за сайт на начальной странице. Так делать не принято. Для тех, кому это интересно выделяют отдельную страницу - About
- Tooltip с примерами работ - он должен быть анимированным и изображения должны быть загружены до его открытия
- Номера телефонов в шапке сайта должны быть каждый на своей строке
- Банер вверху страницы - я ожидал, что он будет ссылкой. Правильнее было бы добавить эту картинку бэкграундом шапки

По поводу сопроводительного письма: навыки обычно перечисляются в резюме и в письме не дублируются

Comment: Мне кажется, в джуниоры должны брать даже если человек языка не знает.

Comment: Согласен. Если все будут искать программера с опытом работы, то где начинать тогда джуниору?

Answer (score 0):

Размести подробное резюме на одном из сайтов и дальше скидывай только ссылку. Причем в резюме опиши технологии, которыми владеешь, портфолио, расскажи немного о себе, не стоит рассказывать только о программировании, работодатели ценят всесторонне развитых личностей, поэтому стоит рассказать о своих хобби, увлечениях. Возраст можно не указывать, это не должно быть важным фактором при отборе кандидатов.

Comment: Как правило, всесторонняя развитость ограничивается обсуждением тёлок, бухла, политики и успеха. Много кто скажет, почему факторкольцо по простому идеалу является полем? А с кем можно обсудить старое киберпанковское аниме? А кого можно считать близким по духу, потому что он тоже слушает сырой блэк-метал и угорает по депрессивной философии? Кто сможет высказать свое мнение после прочтения рассказов Эдгара По? А на пальцах рассказать алгоритм построения матрицы алгеброгеометрического кода на эрмитовой кривой? Экстраверты не могут в увлечения.

Comment: Сейчас стало просто модно выворачивать себя наизнанку на публику. Сходил отложить личинку - написал твит, сменил статус в скайпе и выложил фотку в инстаграмм и контакт. Увидел человека - уже обязательно надо добавить в 100500 своих друзей впашке. Задал вопрос коллеге, которого в первый раз в жизни увидел - уже бежишь подтверждать его навыки в линкедин. Может, это везде требуют?

Comment: Зачем сразу в крайность все переводить? Я имел ввиду, например, написать, что занимаешься каким-нибудь видом спорта. Среди знакомых программистов многие занимаются спортом. Почему бы об этом не написать в резюме?